# Need help with artist name seal (Characters identified: 文丘德之印)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Could anyone help me identify this artist? It is on a silk ink painting. Thank you.
My Chinese is not that good but usually, I get by with dictionaries. However, seal script is new for me. I found some good tips and resources here but still struggling. Top to bottom and right to left as I understand?
[image: An image of a red square artist seal on silk]

Comment: the left bottom one is a distorted character “印”, in seal script. the left component of the right bottom character looks like heart “心” 

Comment: Thank you. I will keep on exploring.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

文立德之印 (文立德's seal)

1: 文 2: 立 3: 德 4: 之 5: 印

###### His homepage and masterpiece: [文立德](http://www.guoxue.com/shj/l/wendeli/index.htm)

###### Introduction by Chinese:

文立德, 笔名艺德, 一九四八年生于北京民间艺人之家, 自幼受艺术熏陶, 从而酷爱绘画艺术.

现为中国书画家研究会一级会员, 专业国画师, 国家书画人材研修中心高级研修员, 湖社画会会员, 中国北京民间文艺家协会会员. 曾为北京彩塑厂金属工艺品厂专职设计人员.

###### Translation:

Wen Lide, pen name Yide, born in 1948 in a family of folk artists in Beijing, he was influenced by art since childhood, so he loves painting.

He is currently a first-level member of the Chinese Painting and Calligraphy Research Association, a professional Chinese painter, a senior researcher of the National Painting and Calligraphy Talent Training Center, a member of the HuShe Painting Association, and a member of the Beijing Folk Artists Association in China. He used to be a full-time designer for the Metal Crafts Factory of Beijing Painted Sculpture Factory.

Comment: it seems more like the character “丘” http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=丘 , than the character “立” http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=立 ; imo 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻, 昨天我询问了中国的篆刻论坛的网友, 他们的意思是, 从字法上看确实是丘, 但谷歌上查不到"文丘德"的任何信息, 而文立德是一位画家, 所以我的推测是, "It is on a silk ink painting", 可能由于是丝绸材质的原因导致印章有缺损.

Comment: yes, maybe  it’s an opinion  btw, i’ve impression that the seal maker has incorrect knowledge of seal script 